# Trabajo con fechas en c++ Builder

Tags: c++, c++builder

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Builder c++ 10.3 que se conecta a una base de Datos Access. En mi pc local y mi región funciona bien los insert y update que hago con las fechas en la Base de Datos. Pero al probar mi código en otra región da error.
¿Cómo puedo garantizar que mi código funcione en cualquier región?

```
....
TDateTime fi (fecha1);
TDateTime ff = fecha2;
valor += FormatDateTime("dd mm yyyy hh nn ss", ff);
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traducción de una respuesta a [Current date/time in TDateTime variable](http://Current%20date/time%20in%20TDateTime%20variable)

> Ten en cuenta que en Windows, internamente, llama a la función `GetLocalTime( )` de la API Win32, que devuelve la fecha/hora del sistema en la zona horaria local. Para obtener la fecha/hora actual del sistema en UTC, **debemos** escribir nuestra propia función que llame a `GetSystemTime( )` en lugar de a `GetLocalTime( )`:

```
TDateTime __fastcall NowUTC( ) {
    SYSTEMTIME SystemTime;
    ::GetSystemTime(&SystemTime);
    return EncodeDate(SystemTime.wYear, SystemTime.wMonth, SystemTime.wDay) + EncodeTime( SystemTime.wHour, SystemTime.wMinute, SystemTime.wSecond, SystemTime.wMilliseconds );
}
```

Comment: relacionada: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12399029/8663418